# present View Controller on click of Bar Button items

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have included numerous `ViewControllers` and as per the requirements, all the ViewControllers must contain the two same custom `BarButton` items(settings,help) in the right and so i created a separate class extending `NSObject` and included two `UIButtons` in it.

In all the ViewControllers, i imported this class and set barButtons like this:

```
    NavigationBarButtonItems *nav=[[NavigationBarButtonItems alloc]init];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [nav BarButtonItems];
```

where, **`NavigationBarButtonItems`** is the class containing two custom Buttons in **`-(NSArray *)BarButtonItems;`** method.

Everything worked perfect. But Here is the problem, i created a viewController for one of the barButtons, say, `'settings'` and i cant figure out how to present this **ViewController(settings)** when settings barButton is clicked as settings barButton is included in almost all the viewControllers.

Help me out. Thanks!

Comment: present the settings view controller modally, on the bar button click event. You may also provide a close button on the settings view, to dismiss that view controller

Answer (score 0):

In the custom class Create the button like this.

```
-(void)createSettingbutton:(id)FromClass {

//Create Add category Button

 UIButton *addSettingButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
addSettingButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[addSettingButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
**[addSettingButton addTarget:FromClass action:@selector(ButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];**

UIBarButtonItem *_addSettingButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:addSettingButton];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:_addSettingButton];

[_addSettingButton release];
_addSettingButton=nil;
}
```

Now add the following code in the `viewcontroller` where you want to add the setting button.

```
[self createSettingbutton:self];//Second self is the parameter which is passed to 'FromClass' Variable.
```

Now in the same viewcontroller  add the action for setting button

```
-(void)ButtonAction
    {
      [self.view addSubview:mSettingView.view];
//or
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mSettingView animated:YES]

    }
```

Comment: `[self createSettingbutton:self];` -> you dont declare `createSettingButton` in the class where you want to display barButtons. So, how can you call the method like **[self methodname]?**. Shouldn't it be like: **[customClassObject createSettingButton:self];**?

Comment: yeah..Sorry.. It should be like this : [customClassObject createSettingButton:self];. Actually I created a category of uiviewcontroller as my custom class so I wrote: [self createSettingbutton:self];.